# Restoring SMS database in Marshmallow

Tags: sms, backup

My SMS database has gotten very large (45k+ messages) and as such, backing up and restoring it with SMS Backup & Restore literally takes hours. Years ago, I used to just copy/restore the mmssms.db file whenever I changed ROMs.

I just tried it on my Nexus 6P on Marshmellow, but Textra/Messaging refuses to read the messages in the database file. I tried changing the permissions to 660 and the owner/group to radio/radio, but Google Play Services stops responding when I open Messaging. None of the messages appear.

Is there something I'm missing here?